# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts for "quick-fix" options in CLion?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clion, jetbrains-ide

In CLion, when I hover my mouse over an area highlighed orange, like this:

[image]

I get a context menu pop up and tell me how to fix the problem that CLang-tidy has found:

[image]

How can I change the keyboard shortcut for actioning the fix from `Alt+Shift+Enter` to whatever I want? (There doesn't seem to be a way to change these shortcuts from the `settings` menu.

Comment: I could not find anything for that shortcut either .. must be hardcoded one... Question though: if you already using your mouse ... why do you need to change a shortcut? If you are using keyboard the `Alt+Enter` will show all applicable fixes and intentions (and that shortcut can be customized for sure).

Comment: True, its a small thing, but sometimes the popup disappears when I try to click on the fix. Plus, I like my shortcuts, if it saves me a fraction of a second I'm happy :). Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: If you will not get any answers with concrete "Yes, here is how" or "Not possible right now" .. just file a Feature Request ticket. Such functionality would be an IDE wide feature (if implemented will become available in all IDEA-based IDEs) so can be reported directly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA (you can also report it in CLion project, I'm sure devs will move it there anyway if no existing solution is available).